# Logstash:Filter configuration for multiline log

Tags: logstash, kibana-4, logstash-configuration

I am trying to parse this multi line log using logstash. My log looks like below

```
   ==> /var/log/mail/log/alerting.log <==

    2016/01/30 08:40:29 , worker_1 , 

    {u'name': u'high', u'type': u'alert', u'alertid': 1122, u'queue_in_time': u'2016-01-30 08:40:29', u'path': u'/var/log/mail/log/alert.log'}
```

But I am not sure how to set up the configuration file. My config file looks like this :

```
    input {
      file {
        path => "/logs/var/alerts.log"
        type => "queue"
        start_position => "beginning"
        codec =>multiline{
                    pattern => "==>"
                    negate => true
                    what => previous
}
}
}
filter {

    if [type] == 'application'{
            date {
        match => [ "timestamp" , "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" ]

                    }
        }
    }

    output {
      stdout { }
    }
```

Can anybody tell me how to configure the filter for this kind of logs ?
I am new to ELK stack and is not able to understand how to configure the config file for parsing custom logs.

Comment: The multiline config seems to match your input.  You don't mention the problem, though.  What does an event look like when it's printed to stdout?

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that update. Another issue is I am not sure how to configure filter for this kind of log. Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How you filter it is a personal preference.  Do you want to drop all events that aren't "alerts"?  It's all up to you.

Comment: I am interested in the event timestamp, name, type, alertid, queue_in_time. I have created mapping in es for this. Need to get the values from these fields. I am not sure how to get this done by reading the logstash documentation.

Comment: If your question is about how to parse your (now combined) message, that's a job for the grok{} filter.  Once you get the json into its own field, you can pass that to the json{} filter and it will make more fields for you.

Comment: Can you tell me how to configure the grok filter in the above context. I am not able to figure it out myself.

Comment: Try something and post what you have if you get stuck.